# Coins dancing for a very long time when animated with physics simulation

Tags: physics

I have put several coins above a table and I want physics simulation to make them fall on a table. So far, I have almost succeeded, but some coins dance for a very long time on the table (nearly 21s!).

The table is set as passive, shape for collision = box, collision margin set to 0.000001m.
Coins are set as actives, shape for collision = cylinder, collision margin set to 0.000001m as well.

Friction is set to 1 and bounce to 0 for both the table and the coins.

With these parameters, the simulation doesn't look very realistic. Does anyone know how I could improve it?

My file can be downloaded here : [image]

Comment: hello maybe share your file (only the coin with the problem and the surface)

Comment: File added as asked.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the bake, choose *Shape > Convex Hull* instead of *Cylinder* which seems to work better (not sure why).

Comment: Maybe the ngon isn't poked, and so it's running calcs on a shape that is being triangulated differently at times

Comment: Oh OK this may explain, thanks

Comment: Triangulating both faces of the coins without any improvement, but changing the shapes from cylinder to convex hull makes the difference. The result is now much more realistic. Nevertheless,, it's a very surprising solution!

Comment: I think Allen was talking about the virtual cylinder if you choose this option under Shape?